# How do I hide a column when printing a DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have in the last of all rows of a DataGridView a "remove" button. I want to not show the remove button when I print it. How can I do this? Also I need to not show the place of the remove button.

I tried setting the `Visible` property of the column to `False`, but that did not hide the column from the printout.

```
Me.DataGridView1.Columns("Remove").Visible = False
With DataGridView1
    Using fmt As New StringFormat With {
        .Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
        .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
        .Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter,
        .FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.LineLimit Or StringFormatFlags.NoWrap
    }

        Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top

        Using headerFont As New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)

            Do While mRow < .RowCount
                Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
                Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
                Dim h As Single = 0

                For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                    Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                    If newpage Then
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, headerFont, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)  '
                    Else
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), headerFont, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                    End If
                    x += rc.Width
                    h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
                Next
                newpage = False
                y += h
                mRow += 1
                If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                    e.HasMorePages = True
                    mRow -= 1
                    newpage = True
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Loop
        End Using
    End Using
    mRow = 0
End With
```

Comment: This is just a guess but `For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells`. I suspect that Remove is still part of the Cells collection even though it is not visible in the grid. You may have to use a For loop instead and indexes to identity what to print.

Comment: post the example code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find the index of the column you do not want to print, then you can check that index when iterating over the cells and simply skip over that iteration, something like this:

```
Me.DataGridView1.Columns("Remove").Visible = False

Dim skipRowNum = DataGridView1.Columns("Remove").Index

With DataGridView1
    Using fmt As New StringFormat With {
        .Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
        .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
        .Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter,
        .FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.LineLimit Or StringFormatFlags.NoWrap
    }

        Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top

        Using headerFont As New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)

            Do While mRow < .RowCount
                Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
                Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
                Dim h As Single = 0

                For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                    If cell.ColumnIndex = skipRowNum Then
                        Continue For
                    End If

                    Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                    If newPage Then
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, headerFont, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)  '
                    Else
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), headerFont, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                    End If
                    x += rc.Width
                    h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
                Next

                newPage = False
                y += h
                mRow += 1

                If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                    e.HasMorePages = True
                    mRow -= 1
                    newpage = True
                    Exit Sub
                End If

            Loop
        End Using
    End Using
    mRow = 0
End With
```

You could easily extend that to exclude more than one column from being printed by using a List(Of Integer) for the columns to be skipped.

Comment: dear it worked fine there is on problem when show the datagridview data in  print Preview   dialog box then a lot of space blank from right side

Comment: Is there a lot of space simply because there are not enough columns to fill the space? (P.S. You can save a lot of paper by printing to the "Microsoft Print to PDF" or "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" printers.)

Comment: dear you have add in code  the column alignment from left to right in digit (number)

Comment: @gkan12 Sorry, I do not understand what you meant in that comment. All I did was add in the code for `skipRowNum`; I did not add in any code for column alignment.

Comment: dear where is the alignment number from left and right because my data not showing good on printperivew

Comment: @gkan12 If you want to adjust the horizontal position of the output, you will need to work out how wide one row is printed and then use that to calculate how much *extra* to add to `Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left`. That should be asked as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim skipRowNum = DataGridView1.Columns("Column1").Index
        With DataGridView1
            Using fmt As New StringFormat With {
                .Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                .Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter,
                .FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.LineLimit Or StringFormatFlags.NoWrap
            }
                Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top
                y = y + e.MarginBounds.Y + 30
                Using headerFont As New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)

                    Do While mRow < .RowCount
                        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
                        Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
                        Dim h As Single = 0
                        x = x + e.MarginBounds.X + 180
                        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                            If cell.ColumnIndex = skipRowNum Then
                                Continue For
                            End If
                            Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                            If newpage Then
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, headerFont, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)  '
                            Else
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), headerFont, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                            End If
                            x += rc.Width
                            h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
                        Next
                        newpage = False
                        y += h
                        mRow += 1

                        If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                            e.HasMorePages = True
                            mRow -= 1
                            newpage = True
                            Exit Sub
                        End If

                    Loop
                End Using
            End Using
            mRow = 0
        End With
```